# Why does the counter incremented using INCR instruction not equal the number of requests when the concurrency of the HTTP request increases?

Tags: python, node.js, redis, load-testing, locust

I am doing the load testing with the Redis server. I wanted to test the `INCR` operation in redis, where I initialize the counter to `1` (by setting a key named total-calls) and then for each incoming request, I increase the counter by 1. So after 3000 requests, the counter should be 3000, after 8000 requests counter must be 8000.

For this, I created a simple `NodeJS` script running express and a simple middleware that increments a counter. I used [loadtest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadtest)
for the load testing. Everything works fine, when there is no concurrency but the results diverge by `1` , `3` or `5` when the I increase the concurrency. I cannot understand the reason for this.

So for the input test where concurrency is 1 and the number of requests are 3000:

```
loadtest -n 3000 -c 1 http://localhost:3000
```

the redis `get total-calls` command gives the expected result of `3000`.

But if I increase the concurrency, to 5 and run the same command after removing the previous key from redis, I get total count as 3001. Why does that happen?

```
loadtest -n 3000 -c 5 http://localhost:3000
```

and on further increasing the number of requests to 8000, the total count becomes 8003. I cannot understand the reason for this.

The code that gets hit by the loadtest:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const Redis = require("./redis-wrapper");

const client = new Redis();
const maxCallsAllowed = 50000

const requestCounter = async (req, resp, next) => {
    // Increment the request counter
    const redis = client.redis;
    if(await redis.exists("total-calls") === 1) {
        // Key already exists
        // Increment the key
        await redis.incr("total-calls")
    }else {
        // Key does not exist
        // Set the key
        await redis.set("total-calls", 1)
    }
    next();
}

app.get('/', requestCounter, (req, resp, next) => {
    resp.json({
        status: 'ok'
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Is there something that I am missing? Why is the count more than the number of requests? I also tested this with [locust.io](https://locust.io/) but noticed the same behavior.

Comment: You definitely have a race condition in the above code - in the time between checking for existence and setting a value, other calls can slip in between. I suggest you rely on Redis' default behavior and loose the exists/set instructions. Just call INCR - if the key doesn't exist it will be assumed as 0 and thus the INCR will set it to 1.

Comment: @ItamarHaber I tried this but no help. For 8000 requests with concurrency set to 5, the final counter value is 8004.